# How to create Dockerfile mixins

Tags: docker, plugins, mixins, extensibility

I'm building developer tooling, my users are using docker, and I'd like them to be able to integrate my tooling into their images.

To do so they need to run a selection of extra build steps in their image, to pull in files & set environment variables after the rest of their build has run. The best way I can see to do this would be to provide some kind of partial dockerfile that they can use, like a mixin. I.e. I publish a set of docker commands & files, in a format that they can easily pull into their existing dockerfile.

Are there any simple ways to pull a set of commands into an existing dockerfile like this? Are there any other alternative solutions?

Answer (score 2):

This question probably has many different answers, but I would consider one of these approaches, if any of them is appropriate for your use case:

#### Option 1: Provide base images with `ONBUILD` directives.

If your users can build their images using custom source images, then you can control their build process with your `ONBUILD` directives.

#### Option 2: Use remote shell scripts instead of Docker steps.

Possibly installed on GitHub. Then, your users will just need to add a `RUN` directive like this:

`RUN bash <(curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/You/YourRepo/master/YourScript)`

#### Option 3: Use a templating engine of your choice.

If you are a Rubyist, ERB, if you are a Pythonist, Jinja.
I have developed a command line utility specifically designed for configuration templating that might be of interest - see [kojo](https://github.com/dannyben/kojo).